# Convert u16string to unsigned long long

Tags: c++, string

How can I convert `std::u16string` to `unsigned long long`, just as I would do it with a regular `std::string` using `std::stoull`?
I would also generalize this question to other numeric types as I haven't managed to find any recipes for convertion from `std::u16string` to any other numeric type.

Comment: There is no `u16toull`. Converting `std::u16string` to `std::string` and using `std::stoull` is probably the easiest workaround.

Comment: @Osyotr isn't it safer to convert to `wstring` then?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. But converting to `std::wstring` will probably be noop on windows.